# How to format date that looks like this (20200326) MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have two fields with dates in them. I am trying to format them to look like `03/26/2020` instead of `20200326`. 
So far my code looks like this changed most of it due to my job guidelines so I can't show you the exact code.

```
SELECT tb.1,tb.2,CONCAT(tb.3,tb.4,tb.5) As Territory, tb.6 AS Start_date, tb.7 AS End Date
```

Comment: I'm a little confused on how the date changes from 2020-03-26 to 2020-01-01.

Comment: I am sorry, I didnt mean that literally. I should edit that 2020-03-26 as you said. I was just putting numbers in there for example.

Comment: Is it `2020-03-26` or `20200326`?

Comment: In the column it is 20200326. I am trying to change it to 2020-03-26 in my view when I export in csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `date_format()`:

```
select date_format(datecol, '%d/%m/%Y')
```